# Openssl implementation of RSA-OAEP padding and RFC 3447

Tags: c, openssl, cryptography, rsa, public-key-encryption

Does the RSA-OAEP padding implementation in Openssl is based on the RFC-3447 (section 7.1)?

I am referring to the following API's

```
int RSA_public_encrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);

int RSA_private_decrypt(int flen, unsigned char *from, unsigned char *to, RSA *rsa, int padding);
```

where padding is `RSA_PKCS1_OAEP_PADDING`.

If I use the above API's for my encryption and decryption can i achieve the results as specified in RFC-3447 (section 7.1)?

Comment: Get you some test vectors and find out.

Comment: I am 99% certain it is compatible. The man page says it is based in PKCS #1 ver 2.0, and while rfc 3447 is based on PKCS #1 ver 2.1, they are very similar in the part dealing with OAEP.